# InDesign - how do I know if an image already placed?

Tags: adobe-indesign

I am working on a book with many images, and I want to ensure that I place each picture only once. Is there a way to tell indesign to to check if image exist before placing it? Or a way to define a preflight profile for it?
Thank you,
Omer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to see a list in the `links` panel.

It shows the number of times and the page number it appears on.

example:

```
Name                | ! | Pg |
--------------------|---|----|
my-image.psd (2)    |   |    |
     my-image.psd   |   |  1 |
     my-image.psd   |   |  4 |
```

Comment: Thank, that look very promising. Is there a way to know it when placing the image?

Comment: I didn't find anything built in. You could try to find a script or sort the files by count and just keep an eye on it when placing in files. Sorry